# Pandas groupby, filter and aggregate

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
employee_name   age location    salary
Harish          31  Mumbai      450000
Marina          30  Mumbai      600000
Meena           31  Pune        750000
Sachin          32  Mumbai      1200000
Tarun           27  Mumbai      1400000
Mahesh          41  Pune        1500000
Satish          42  Delhi       650000
Heena           34  Delhi       800000
```

What I want out of this dataframe is all the employees in the age group > 30 & < 35 in all different locations earning maximum salary

My desired dataframe would be

```
employee_name       age     location     salary
Sachin              32      Mumbai       1200000
Meena               31      Pune         750000
Heena               34      Delhi        800000
```

I am doing following in pandas, but its giving an error

```
df.groupby('location').filter(lambda x : (x['age'] > 30) & (x['age'] < 35))['salary'].max()
```

How do I do it in pandas?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: TypeError: filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool

Comment: filter here will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just filter first, then find the rows with max values:

```
(df.loc[df['age'].between(31,34)]
   .sort_values('salary')
   .drop_duplicates('location', keep='last')
)
```

Output:

```
  employee_name  age location   salary
2         Meena   31     Pune   750000
7         Heena   34    Delhi   800000
3        Sachin   32   Mumbai  1200000
```

Comment: You code gives `max` value in **each** column. So the `age` will most likely be `34` always.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `idxmax`, notice filter here will not work

```
df.loc[df[df['age'].between(31,34)].groupby('location')['salary'].idxmax()]
Out[110]: 
  employee_name  age location   salary
7         Heena   34    Delhi   800000
3        Sachin   32   Mumbai  1200000
2         Meena   31     Pune   750000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this option:

```
df = df.query('age > 30 & age < 35')
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset="age", keep="last")
print(df)
```